# How can I change language of my application from english to arabic language?

Tags: android

I have to make multi language application. When i am converting language from English to Arabic, whole view of application is changed for example my navigation drawer shifted from left to right. But i want to translate only text..

I have written this code.

```
 if (language.equalsIgnoreCase("English")) {
                    languageToLoad = "en";
                } else if (language.equalsIgnoreCase("Arabic")) {
                    languageToLoad = "ar";
                }

                Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
                Locale.setDefault(locale);
                Configuration config = new Configuration();
                config.locale = locale;
                getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/a/49901058/8089770

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Locale but keep left-to-right and other phone orientations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37120673/change-locale-but-keep-left-to-right-and-other-phone-orientations)

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**:First of all you need create layout-ar and values-ar(this will contain your string file where you will put your arabic string)

**Step 2**:You need to store your language in SharedPreference,I store using SharedPreferenceHelper class.

Step a:To get language

```
        SharedPreferencesHelper sharedPreferencesHelper = SharedPreferencesHelper.getSharedInstance(this);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = sharedPreferencesHelper.getLanguage();
        String lng = sharedPreferences.getString("language", "en");
```

b:To store language

```
        SharedPreferencesHelper sharedPreferencesHelperlang = SharedPreferencesHelper.getSharedInstance(this);
        sharedPreferencesHelperlang.saveLanguage("en");
```

**SharedPreferencesHelper.java**

public class SharedPreferencesHelper {

```
Context context;
public  static  String LANGUAGE = "language";
public static SharedPreferencesHelper sharedInstance;


public static SharedPreferencesHelper getSharedInstance(Context context){

    if(sharedInstance == null){
        sharedInstance = new SharedPreferencesHelper(context);
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

public SharedPreferencesHelper(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

public void saveLanguage(String lng){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(LANGUAGE,context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("language",lng);
    editor.commit();
}

public SharedPreferences getLanguage(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("language",context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences;
}
```

}

Step 3: Add this class of locale helper which will check for language change through sharedpreference.

```
public class LocaleHelper {

    private static final String SELECTED_LANGUAGE = "Locale.Helper.Selected.Language";

    public static void onAttach(Context context) {
        String lang = getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
        setLocale(context);
    }

    public static void onAttach(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        String lang = getPersistedData(context, defaultLanguage);
        setLocale(context);
    }

    public static String getLanguage(Context context) {
        return getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
    }

    public static Context setLocale(Context context) {

        /*if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            updateResources(context, language);
        }else {
            updateResourcesLegacy(context, language);
        }*/
//        GetPreferencesDetail getPreferencesDetail = new GetPreferencesDetail(context);
//        getPreferencesDetail.getAllDetails();
//        String language = GetPreferencesDetail.LANGAUGE;
//        persist(context, language);

        SharedPreferencesHelper sharedPreferencesHelper = new SharedPreferencesHelper(context);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = sharedPreferencesHelper.getLanguage();
        String language = sharedPreferences.getString("language", "en");

        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Resources res = context.getResources();
        Configuration config = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
            config.setLocale(locale);
            context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
        } else {
            config.locale = locale;
            res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
        }
        return context;
    }

    private static String getPersistedData(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return preferences.getString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, defaultLanguage);
    }

    private static void persist(Context context, String language) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        editor.putString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, language);
        editor.apply();
    }

}
```

I think this much should do it.